# How to count non-null columns per group?

Tags: python, pandas

I started from raw data that looks like this:

```
  Case  Final    Pre    Post   
  1     A        Z      X  
        Z               V  
  2     B                  
        Y                  
  3     A        Z      Y  
        Z               U  
        W                  
  4     C        W        
        Z                  
  5     C        X      Z  
        X                  
        Z
```

then did a forward fill:

```
df['Case'] = df['Case'].ffill()
```

like so:

```
  Case  Final    Pre    Post   
  1     A        Z      X  
  1     Z        NaN    V  
  2     B        NaN    NaN
  2     Y        NaN    NaN
  3     A        Z      Y  
  3     Z        NaN    U  
  3     W        NaN    NaN
  4     C        W      NaN
  4     Z        NaN    NaN
  5     C        X      Z  
  5     X        NaN    NaN
  5     Z        NaN    NaN
```

What I want is to count the number of cases in each column where the column is not null:

```
  Case: 5
  Final: 5
  Pre: 4
  Post: 3
```

**Output Explanation:**

1- Group by the first column `Case`.

2- Even if one value of the column is not null (including `Case` column itself) then count++ (increment the not null count by 1).

Comment: case is not null at all times, why does it say 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df.notna().groupby(df['Case']).any().sum()
#oldier pandas versions
s = df.notnull().groupby(df['Case']).any().sum()
print (s)
Case     5
Final    5
Pre      4
Post     3
dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

First check non missing values by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
print (df.notna())
    Case  Final    Pre   Post
0   True   True   True   True
1   True   True  False   True
2   True   True  False  False
3   True   True  False  False
4   True   True   True   True
5   True   True  False   True
6   True   True  False  False
7   True   True   True  False
8   True   True  False  False
9   True   True   True   True
10  True   True  False  False
11  True   True  False  False
```

And then aggregate by column `Case` with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
print (df.notnull().groupby(df['Case']).any())
      Case  Final    Pre   Post
Case                           
1     True   True   True   True
2     True   True  False  False
3     True   True   True   True
4     True   True   True  False
5     True   True   True   True
```

And last `sum` values for count `True`s processes like `1`.

Comment: that explains why you're so fast ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Case', as_index=False)\
            .agg(lambda col: col.notnull().any())\
            .astype(bool)\
            .sum(axis='rows')
```

We group by `'Case'`, and work out if there is any non-null value for each column. So

```
df.groupby('Case', as_index=False)\
  .agg(lambda col: col.notnull().any())
```

Gives us:

```
   Case  Final    Pre   Post
0   1.0   True   True   True
1   2.0   True  False  False
2   3.0   True   True   True
3   4.0   True   True  False
4   5.0   True   True   True
```

Using `.astype(bool)` sets every value in the `'Case'` column to be `True` as they are non-zero, and then summing with `axis='rows'` gives us the total of each column (where `True` becomes 1 and `False` 0), giving us:

```
Case     5
Final    5
Pre      4
Post     3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df.index = df.Case

df.apply(lambda x: len(x[pd.isna(x) == False].index.unique()))
```

Out:

```
Case     5
Final    5
Pre      4
Post     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's perfectly precise.

Comment: @Joe What do you mean? There no any changes to NAN. This code mean: first, index is Case, then for every column take only non-nan values, take index from them and take length of unique values (so we have a length of list with unique values of Case for raws with non-nan values).

Comment: @Joe, so.. my code works for me if I change last three values of Final to nan and return 4 as output. I don't understand.. Do you mean it's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i just misunderstood

Comment: `x[pd.isna(x) == False]` could be shortened to `x[~pd.isna(x)]` but I think `.apply()` will generally be slower than direct methods.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(df['Case'], as_index=False).any().astype(bool).sum()
```

#### output

```
Case     5
Final    5
Pre      4
Post     3
```